# Ошибка при добавлении данных в SQLite TelegramBot

Tags: sqlite, telegram-bot, telebot, telethon

Имеется БД SQLite. Библиотека python-telegram-api. При добавлении данных возникает ошибка (см.ниже)

Вызов БД осуществляется кодом:

```
         db = database.SQLiteDB("db.db")
```

Добавление записи:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_handler(call: telebot.types.CallbackQuery):
if call.data in languages.languages_list:
    user_id = call.message.chat.id
    db.set_attribute(call.message.chat.id, "Language", call.data)
    if db.get_attribute_value(user_id, "Sex") is None:
        bot.edit_message_text(
            chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
            message_id=call.message.message_id,
            text=languages.languages_map[call.data]['sex_message'],
            reply_markup=markups.keyboard_sex
        )
```

Определение метода добавления:

```
    def get_attribute_value(self, user_id: int, attribute_name: str) -> str:
    """
    :Возвращение значения первого попавшего атрибута
    :param user_id: уникальный идентификатор user
    :param attribute_name: название атрибута, котрый ищем
    :return: значения первого попавшего атрибута
    """
    self.cursor.execute('''SELECT {Attribute} 
                           FROM Users
                           WHERE Id="{UserId}"
                        '''.format(Attribute=attribute_name, UserId=user_id))
    self.conn.commit()
    return self.cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Ошибка:

```
2020-10-18 00:35:26,685 (util.py:75 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot:   File "main.py", line 114, in <module>
    bot.polling()
  File "C:\Users\gacrux\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 427, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\gacrux\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 451, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\gacrux\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 118, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "C:\Users\gacrux\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\gacrux\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 69, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 27, in command_handler
    if db.add_user_if_not_exist(user_id):
  File "C:\telegrambot-Asyn_programming_testing\database.py", line 40, in add_user_if_not_exist
    self.cursor.execute('''SELECT Id FROM Users
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 4048 and this is thread id 10408.
```

Какие советы по избежанию можете дать?

Answer (score 0):

Замените подключение бд на `sqlite3.connect("db.db", check_same_thread=False)`.
Если не будет работать замените импорт sqlite3 на `import sqlite3`(вы будете использовать встроенный sqlite3)